# Bot Framework and LUIS An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I upgrade my bot framework to 3.13.0.3 and my LUIS dialog stop working. My bot start but when I write the word about the intent the bot show again the initial message and stay in this loop.

I did verify the app ID and key, If I make a request to LUIS from the browser it works fine, but from the bot is like not make the request.

I did train and publish the LUIS model again

From visual studio and Azure deployment the behavior is the same, when type the LUIS intent the bot shows again the start message. The LUISIntent is in spanish "vacantes" or "registrar"

Before the upgrade the bot works fine and the LUIS dialog works.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using MP_BotMVP.SupportClasses;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;

namespace MP_BotMVP.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        public RootDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppId"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIKey"],
            domain: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIHostName"])))
        {
        }

        [LuisIntent("")]
        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            string strUserName = "Usuario";
            try
            {
                strUserName = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserNameKey);
            }
            catch { }

            string message = string.Format(DialogText.No_Endiendo,strUserName);

            await context.PostAsync(message);

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            await this.SendWelcomeMessage(context);
        }

        private async Task SendWelcomeMessage(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"{DialogText.Saludo_Inicial}");

            PromptDialog.Text(context, this.GetUserNameAfter, DialogText.Pedir_Nombre);
        }

        private async Task GetUserNameAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var userName = await result;

            context.UserData.SetValue(DialogText.UserNameKey, userName);

            await context.PostAsync(string.Format(DialogText.Bienvenido, userName.ToString()));
        }

        [LuisIntent("Saludo y Presentacion")]
        public async Task Greetings(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            await this.SendWelcomeMessage(context);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Registrar CV")]
        public async Task RecordCV(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            string strUserName = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserNameKey);

            string strLink = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MP_CV_Url"];
            string strResponse = string.Format(DialogText.Registrar_CV, strUserName, strLink);

            await context.PostAsync(strResponse);

            await this.SendMayIHelp(context);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Buscar Vacantes")]
        public Task SearchJob(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            string strUserName = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserNameKey);

            string strResponse = string.Format(DialogText.Buscar_Vacante, strUserName);

            PromptDialog.Text(context, this.SearchJobAfter, strResponse);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task SearchJobAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var userCity = await result;

            context.UserData.SetValue(DialogText.UserSelectedCityKey, userCity);

            PromptDialog.Text(context, this.SearchJobAreaAfter, DialogText.Buscar_Area);
        }

        private async Task SearchJobAreaAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var userArea = await result;

            context.UserData.SetValue(DialogText.UserSelectAreaKey, userArea);

            string strUserName = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserNameKey);
            string strUserCity = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserSelectedCityKey);
            string strUserArea = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserSelectAreaKey);
            string strLink = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MP_CV_Url"];

            string strResponse = string.Format(DialogText.Buscando_Vacante, strUserName, strUserCity, strUserArea);

            await context.PostAsync(strResponse);

            List<string> l_strOpps = SQLDB.Get_Opportunities(strUserCity, strUserArea);

            if (l_strOpps.Count > 0)
            {
                await context.PostAsync(string.Format(DialogText.Si_Resultados, strUserName, l_strOpps.Count));
                foreach (string str in l_strOpps)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync(str);
                }

                await context.PostAsync(string.Format(DialogText.Vacantes_InfoExtra, strUserName, strLink));

                await this.SendMayIHelp(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync(DialogText.No_Resultados);

                PromptDialog.Text(context, this.SearchJobAreaAfter, DialogText.No_Resultados_Nuevamente);
            }
        }

        [LuisIntent("Ayuda Adicional")]
        public async Task GetInfo(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            string strUserName = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserNameKey);

            string strResponse = string.Format(DialogText.Ayuda_Adicional, strUserName);

            await context.PostAsync(strResponse);
        }

        private async Task SendMayIHelp(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync(DialogText.Mas_Ayuda);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Calificar")]
        public Task GetFeedback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            foreach (var ent in result.Entities)
            {
                if ((ent.Entity.ToLower() == "si") || (ent.Entity.ToLower() == "calificar"))
                {
                    PromptDialog.Text(context, this.FeedbackAfter, DialogText.Calificar);
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task FeedbackAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var userFeedback = await result;

            //TODO --> Grabar en la DB

            string strUserName = context.UserData.GetValue<string>(DialogText.UserNameKey);
            string strResponse = string.Format(DialogText.Despedida, strUserName);
            await context.PostAsync(strResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error in the bot emulator

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2018-02-01T01:07:03.688Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2018-01-31T20:07:03-05:00",
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:32443",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "8jbgkfm83h2a",
    "name": "Bot"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "k9247mmn33ig"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "default-user"
  },
  "membersAdded": [],
  "membersRemoved": [],
  "locale": "en-US",
  "text": "Exception: An error occurred while sending the request.",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "text/plain",
      "content": "   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Luis-ILuisService-QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions.<QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__23.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "replyToId": "6hj7g24i9bgf",
  "id": "974a35c985dd"
}
```

Extract of the error text (attachments.content):

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Luis-ILuisService-QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions.<QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Is your problem that the bot is staying in loop? If so, the reason is that in your `GetUserNameAfter` function, you are posting back the response and not waiting for the next text to go to `MessageReceived`, so at the end of the function after `context.PostAsync`, add `context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);`

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems in your dialog implementation:

### Dialog inheriting from LuisDialog

Have a look to the definition of `LuisDialog` on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L172): you will see that the call to LUIS is made in `MessageReceived` method. Or this method is called using `context.Wait(MessageReceived);` which is never used in your dialog because you are overriding `StartAsync(IDialogContext context)`.

As a consequence, you wil never call LUIS and go into your methods matching the intents.

To correct that point, add `context.Wait(MessageReceived);`after your welcome process, basically at the end of `GetUserNameAfter`.

### End of methods

One important thing from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#im-using-the-bot-builder-sdk-for-net-how-can-i-troubleshoot-issues-with-my-bot):

> **Ensure all dialog methods end with a plan to handle the next message.**
>
> All IDialog methods should complete with `IDialogStack.Call`,
> `IDialogStack.Wait`, or `IDialogStack.Done`. These `IDialogStack` methods
> are exposed through the `IDialogContext` that is passed to every IDialog
> method. Calling `IDialogStack.Forward` and using the system prompts
> through the `PromptDialog` static methods will call one of these methods
> in their implementation.

If we follow the flow of your dialog, there are several points where you will be stuck:

- End of `GetUserNameAfter` method execution, where you post a message to the user and then you are not waiting for a message or ending the dialog
- End of `SendMayIHelp` method execution, called by several methods (`RecordCV`, `SearchJobAreaAfter` when count > 0, `GetInfo`, ...), where you post a message to the user and then you are not waiting for a message or ending the dialog
- In `SearchJob` & `GetFeedback`, you should not `return Task.CompletedTask;` after starting a `PromptDialog.Text` because this prompt will resume elsewhere. Add `async` to your methods definitions
- End of `FeedbackAfter` method execution, where you post a message to the user and then you are not waiting for a message or ending the dialog

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the information.

I did try the context.Wait(MessageReceived); and context.Done but the behavior is the same, when the user types the LUIS intent "vacantes" or "registrar" the bot shows the start message again.

The error still the same, Exception: An error occurred while sending the request.

I´m using for App ID LUIS web page, and API Key in the web link for the azure zone

https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/8e701808-8a62-4efa-8cb7-9ef973b7d336?subscription-key=2d5f9a382ecc482587d88b75dd84d76f&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=

Comment: It will be difficult to help more without a complete code to check every possibility

Comment: Nicolas can I send you the code or connect with teamviewer or skype and review the code?